# webprofile 6 missing in openliberty but not in websphere liberty

Tags: open-liberty

Currently we are trying to build a docker image with openliberty 20.0.0.3 with webprofile6 with java 8, we were able to do this with websphere liberty full profile image but not with the full profile image from open-liberty.

Is this something expected?

There is a way to have availble it in open-liberty?

Thanks

Michele

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected, some older versions of jee features are available in websphere liberty only.  You could move to a later version like webProfile-8.0 which is available in open liberty.

Comment: webProfile-7.0 is also available on OpenLiberty